# How can I filter/sort a Drupal view in this way?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have created a content type called PDF Publication with two fields - a pdf file upload field that allows one file to be uploaded and a term reference field where the user selects an area e.g. area1 area2 or area3

I now need to create a view block that shows just the latest pdf uploaded for each area. so the block will show three pdfs - one for each area

I have followed instruction [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638234/drupal-views-display-newest-content-per-taxonomy-limit-to-one-node) and other forums on the Internet but am struggling to do this.

I would be really greatful for some help, thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of you doing it since you have just three areas, is creating One block display with two attachments.

The block contains one area with the most recent pdf, and the two attachment, would contain one area each with the most recent attachment, and link the attachments to the block display.

See Image of how to add an attachment
[image]

UPDATE

When you are using more than one diaplay and are adding a display you want to make sure at the top of the popup dialog you choose for this display, rather than all display. See image below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what do you mean by attachments?

Comment: See update to answer

Comment: I have created the block and two attachments. However when I change the filter criteria for an attachment, the block filter and the other attachment criteria also changes meaning that when I change the filter criteria for one of them, they all change and the view shows 3 of the same pdfs.

Cheers

how can I change the filter criteria for each of the attachments without it affecting the other attachment/block?

Comment: See updated answer